# Is it possible to pass a sourcemaps to grunt-ng-annotate?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I am concatenating some files that then get passed to `ng-annotate` and then minified. Is there a way to pass a sourcemap to `grunt-ng-annotate`?

Comment: Is the sourceMap option ( https://github.com/mzgol/grunt-ng-annotate#sourcemap ) in ng-annotate helpful for your usecase ?

Comment: unfortunately that just tells it to generate a source-map and or where to put it. a value of `true` makes it generate the source-map but at the bottom of the page and a `string` would be the file path to write it to another file.